# Postfix API/Lookup tables for sent messages information

Tags: email, logging, smtp, postfix-mta, data-mining

Currently it seems common practice to parse Postfix log files in order to determine if a message has been sent. Is there an API for Postfix or a look up table in it that yields this information in a manner quicker than parsing (rather lengthy) log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API. You could, however, make use of the [policy delegation protocol](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html) to write a simple policy daemon which logs per message information in a manner that suits you more.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.posty-soft.org

> posty was developed in 2013 by four computer science students at the
>   University of Applied Sciences Rosenheim goal was to create THE open
>   source administration tool for mail server with Postfix and Dovecot.
>
> The posty_API is the core element of the posty softwarestack. It is
>   developed to administrate a mailserver based on Postfix and Dovecot.
>   It offers an easy REST interface which can be used in own applications
>   or with the posty client applications, posty_CLI and posty_webUI.

Comment: posty does not provide any info about sent mails.